# Can you give me a mechanism for the following reaction?

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism

Can you give me a mechanism for the following reaction? Here methyl is not shifting. Other ester group is shifting.

[image]

Comment: What do think? Does the methyl jump --- or not? I believe this has been answered. Edit your query with some ideas. Then I'll look for it.

Comment: Ethoxide is a pretty strong base, where do you think the most acidic proton is?

Comment: This question answers your question https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/89790/regioselectivity-in-claisen-condensation-and-aldol-reaction

Comment: It is claissen condensation happening in equillibrium

Comment: Thank you Waylander, I think H next to carbonyl is more acidic and the first ethoxide grab acidic H.But I have doubt, is there any possibility attack ethoxide to the carbonyl carbon of ring? if it is,next step should go through the ring-opening to get product. I am confused about these two ways.